# U-boot messages regarding partition switches not understood

Tags: debian, boot-loader, u-boot, flash-memory, beagleboneblack

I am using a BeagleBone board with the default Debian image flashed to the internal emmc.

I'm trying to understand the U-boot messages below that I get over serial when the device starts, especially how it reports that `mmc0 is current device` at first , and then later it states that `mmc1(part 0) is current device`.

What is happening here? Is mmc0 the internal emmc memory or the SD card, and why does the boot loader switch from mmc0 to mmc1?

```
U-Boot SPL 2018.09-00002-g0b54a51eee (Sep 10 2018 - 19:41:39 -0500)
Trying to boot from MMC2
Loading Environment from EXT4...
** Unable to use mmc 0:1 for loading the env **

U-Boot 2018.09-00002-g0b54a51eee (Sep 10 2018 - 19:41:39 -0500), Build: 
jenkins-github_Bootloader-Builder-65

CPU  : AM335X-GP rev 2.1
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  512 MiB
No match for driver 'omap_hsmmc'
No match for driver 'omap_hsmmc'
Some drivers were not found
Reset Source: Power-on reset has occurred.
RTC 32KCLK Source: External.
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
Loading Environment from EXT4...
** Unable to use mmc 0:1 for loading the env **
Board: BeagleBone Black
<ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
BeagleBone Black:
Model: SeeedStudio BeagleBone Green Wireless:
BeagleBone: cape eeprom: i2c_probe: 0x54:
BeagleBone: cape eeprom: i2c_probe: 0x55:
BeagleBone: cape eeprom: i2c_probe: 0x56:
BeagleBone: cape eeprom: i2c_probe: 0x57:
Net:   eth0: MII MODE
Could not get PHY for cpsw: addr 0
cpsw, usb_ether
Press SPACE to abort autoboot in 2 seconds
board_name=[A335BNLT] ...
board_rev=[GW1A] ...
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
SD/MMC found on device 0
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc 0:1...
gpio: pin 56 (gpio 56) value is 0
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 0
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 0
gpio: pin 53 (gpio 53) value is 1
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 1
Checking for: /uEnv.txt ...
Checking for: /boot.scr ...
Checking for: /boot/boot.scr ...
Checking for: /boot/uEnv.txt ...
** Invalid partition 3 **
** Invalid partition 4 **
** Invalid partition 5 **
** Invalid partition 6 **
** Invalid partition 7 **
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc1(part 0) is current device
Scanning mmc 1:1...
gpio: pin 56 (gpio 56) value is 0
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 0
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 0
gpio: pin 53 (gpio 53) value is 1
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc1(part 0) is current device
gpio: pin 54 (gpio 54) value is 1
Checking for: /uEnv.txt ...
Checking for: /boot.scr ...
Checking for: /boot/boot.scr ...
Checking for: /boot/uEnv.txt ...
gpio: pin 55 (gpio 55) value is 1
2099 bytes read in 7 ms (292 KiB/s)
Loaded environment from /boot/uEnv.txt
Checking if uname_r is set in /boot/uEnv.txt...
gpio: pin 56 (gpio 56) value is 1
Running uname_boot ...
loading /boot/vmlinuz-4.14.71-ti-r80 ...
10416640 bytes read in 663 ms (15 MiB/s)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, mmc0 is the SD card and mmc1 is the eMMC.  Things are made less clear by the fact that the "Trying to boot from" messages match the devices as numbered by the SoC documentation and are numbered starting from 1 while the later messages follow the normal convention and are numbered starting from 0.

The default boot command on this board will search a number of locations for a valid "thing" to boot, and so that the user can easily try something else, it will look for an SD card (and then look in places on it) for something to boot and then fall back to the eMMC.

Comment: By default the ROM bootloader on the Beaglebone boots from the internal emmc tho. Only when holding down the boot button, it will search for a bootloader on the SD card. However, I am not holding down the button during this. This I don't understand

Comment: ROMBL is only responsible for loading the next stage. Which is SPL (a tiny U-Boot), which loads U-Boot proper. – At that stage it is U-Boots decision where it will look for what and it's not influenced by the SYSBOOT pin strap.